# Enabling Posix Message Queue

Tags: debian, kernel, kernel-modules, posix

I'm trying to write a `C` application tha run on embedded linux device (debian os). I can't create POSIX Message Queue with `mq_open()` method, it returns an error `"Function not implemented"` with `errno`. I found [an answer](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/POSIX-Message-Queues-mq-open-Not-Implemented/td-p/269926) on a forum  that I need to re-compile kernel source with enabling posix mqueue. Is it possible to adding POSIX Message Queue support to running Debian Operating System (as a kernel module), or I have to recompile kernel with `"CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE=y"` ?

Comment: `CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE` is enabled by default `man mq_overview`